# difference between two dates

Tags: .net, winforms

I have 2 dates 1st is system date & 2nd is manually added date.

For example - system date is 02/may/2011 & manually added date is 01/may/2011.

2nd date is less than current date then the date is expire but when the system date is changed, for example - 01/April/2011.

then also its working. I have the output is date is expire. no effects when system date changed.

Comment: What is your question? What is working? What isn't working? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Are you calling the event/method where you do the comparison again after changing the system date ? How is the current date set in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following class: TimeSpan

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Example:

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2002,7,15);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
// Difference in days.
int differenceInDays = ts.Days;
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps the OP, or at least explain to me what he is asking?